# Retrieving json child with php (inside another foreach)

Tags: php, json

I'm triying to retrieve some data from a json file, in this case the json file have a child call "photo" and that child storage several file names, I need to fetch those file names inside an outer foreach. Here is my code:

My JSON file looks like this:

```
    {
        "nigiri": [{
            "code": "NS-1",
            "title": "Maguro",
            "description": "6pc tuna",
            "price": "$10.00",
            "photo": ["HD-21-a.jpg", "HD-21-b.jpg", "HD-21-c.jpg", "HD-21-c.jpg"]
        }, {
            "title": "Scottish",
            "code": "NS-2",
            "price": "$9.50",
            "photo": ["HD-21-a.jpg", "HD-21-b.jpg", "HD-21-c.jpg", "HD-21-c.jpg"],
            "description": "6pc salmon"
        }, {
            "title": "Buri",
            "code": "NS-3",
            "price": "$10.00",
            "photo": "NS-3.jpg",
            "description": "6pc Hamachi"
        }]
    }
```

And my PHP file looks like this:

```php
<?php
    $getfile = file_get_contents('backend/menu.json');
    $jsonfile = json_decode($getfile);
    $type = htmlentities($_GET["type"]);
    if(empty($_GET['type'])) 
    { 
      header('Location: index.php');
      exit; 
    }
?>


// This way I only get the first value

<?php foreach ($jsonfile->$type as $index => $obj): ?>

    <h2>Name of the plate: <?php echo $obj->title; ?></h2>
    <img src="img/plates/thumbs/<?php echo $obj->photo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $obj->title; ?>">

<?php endforeach; ?>


// I want to retrieve the others values from the "photo" child but still inside the previous foreach. I've try this:

<?php foreach ($jsonfile->$type as $index => $obj): ?>

    <h2>Name of the plate: <?php echo $obj->title; ?></h2>

    <?php foreach ($jsonfile->$type->photo as $index => $photos): ?>
    <img src="img/plates/thumbs/<?php echo $photos->photo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $obj->title; ?>">

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You're already looping around `$jsonfile->$type` in the outer loop, you have no reason to do that again in the inner loop. In the outer loop you say that each `$jsonfile->$type` is `$obj` so your inner loop should loop around `$obj->photo` (after checking if it's an array.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's best just to stay in PHP rather than going in and out of HTML:

```
foreach ($jsonfile->$type as $obj) {
    echo "<h2>Name of the plate: $obj->title</h2>\n";
    $photos = is_array($obj->photo) ? $obj->photo : array($obj->photo);
    foreach ($photos as $photo) 
        echo "<img src=\"img/plates/thumbs/$photo\" alt=\"$obj->title\">\n";
}
```

Note that since `$photo` may not be an array, we need to check first before we attempt to iterate it, and if it isn't, make it into one.

Output (for your sample data, with `$type = "nigiri"`):

```
<h2>Name of the plate: Maguro</h2>
<img src="img/plates/thumbs/HD-21-a.jpg" alt="Maguro">
<img src="img/plates/thumbs/HD-21-b.jpg" alt="Maguro">
<img src="img/plates/thumbs/HD-21-c.jpg" alt="Maguro">
<img src="img/plates/thumbs/HD-21-c.jpg" alt="Maguro">
<h2>Name of the plate: Scottish</h2>
<img src="img/plates/thumbs/HD-21-a.jpg" alt="Scottish">
<img src="img/plates/thumbs/HD-21-b.jpg" alt="Scottish">
<img src="img/plates/thumbs/HD-21-c.jpg" alt="Scottish">
<img src="img/plates/thumbs/HD-21-c.jpg" alt="Scottish">
<h2>Name of the plate: Buri</h2>
<img src="img/plates/thumbs/NS-3.jpg" alt="Buri">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mean is you want output photo if you have a lot photos?

```
<?php foreach ($jsonfile->$type as $index => $obj): ?>

<h2>Name of the plate: <?php echo $obj->title; ?></h2>

<?php if (is_array($obj->photo)): ?>

    <?php foreach ($jsonfile->$type->photo as $index => $photos): ?>
    <img src="img/plates/thumbs/<?php echo $photos->photo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $obj->title; ?>">
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else ?>

    <img src="img/plates/thumbs/<?php echo $obj->photo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $obj->title; ?>">

<?php endif; ?>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use nested loops. Something like that:

```
<?php
$getfile = file_get_contents('backend/menu.json');
$jsonfile = json_decode($getfile);
$type = htmlentities($_GET["type"]);
if(empty($_GET['type'])) 
{ 
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit; 
}
?>

<?php foreach ($jsonfile->$type as $index => $obj): ?>

<h2>Name of the plate: <?php echo $obj->title; ?></h2>

<?php if(is_array($obj->photo)): ?>
<?php foreach ($obj->photo as $photo): ?>
   <img src="img/plates/thumbs/<?php echo $photo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $obj->title; ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
   <img src="img/plates/thumbs/<?php echo $obj->photo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $obj->title; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This works!, i get the results but only if they are on an array. If is only one filename it doesn't fetch anything. I tried to mixed with the ´if is_array´ from the other comment but i doesn't work